# jQuery target element using next() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have the following HTML code, I would like to get the style of the 'p' element when clicking on the link.

```
<a href="#" onclick="var state = $(this).next().css('display'); alert(state);"/>Link
<p style="display:none;">Test Div</p>
```

My issue is that I get always 'undefined' instead of 'none'
This is just an exemple, I can use id or class to target the 'p' element but in production I have many links and they have no ids or classes that's why I want to use the 'this' to target the 'p' element.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: That's a weird `a`... they don't officially support shortcut tags like that. If you look at it in the DOM, is the `p` a sibling or a child?

Comment: Your html in the sample code is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because anchors aren't self-closing. Use:

```
<a href="#" onclick="var state = $(this).next().css('display'); alert(state);">Link</a>
<p style="display:none;">Test Div</p>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/QxCBr/)**